# Is there a way to attach console.log to firebase analytics event?

Tags: react-native, firebase-analytics

I am setting up firebase analytics for my React Native app. Is it possible to attach a `console.log` that fires each time `firebase.analytics().logEvent()` is called? I want to be able to see the event name and params in the console.log. I know I can check in the DebugView in Firebase, but just having it logged to the console seems a bit faster. Appreciate any input.

Comment: I would simply make a function which calls both of those things and use that function instead of logEvent. Alternatively you could use patch-package to change the code of logEvent to make it do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Per the comment, it would be more economical to create a global method that sends the data to Analytics and console together.

You can read about Global Helpers [**HERE**](https://dev.to/acro5piano/global-helper-in-react-native--32l4).

```
module.exports = function(payload) {  
   firebase.analytics().logEvent()  
   console.log(payload);
}

_.Log(payload);
```

This allows you to also introduce filters and edge-case scenarios within your app as needed including debug mode and alerts from within your app.